# difference between usage of @RabbitListener() and usage of DirectMessageListenerContainer in consuming from a rabbitMQ in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to configure concurrent consumers in spring to consume messages from RabbitMQ, in order to achieve that i have configured consumers in two ways

1.annotated a method with **@RabbitListener(queues = "name of queue")**

2.**implementing "MessageListener" interface and overriding onMessage(Message message)**

In my case both the ways worked fine, but i am unable to figure out what is the advantage/disadvantage of using @RabbitListener() for starting a consumer over the other way.

Also adding to that i have configured "DirectMessageListenerContainer" in my configuration and mapped it to "MessageListener" implementation to achieve concurrent consumers, my question here is can we do the same mapping for consumer implemented through @RabbitListener() and if so how.  I couldnt find any source on how a consumer started with a @RabbitListener() annotated method can be configured with a "DirectMessageListenerContainer"

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`@RabbitListener` is simply a higher-level abstraction. It uses the listener container underneath.

When using spring boot, use the [...listener.type](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.rabbitmq.listener.type) application property to specify which type of container you want.

The default is `simple`.